# Phusion Passenger got an g++: Internal error

Tags: apache2, rvm, passenger

I have successfully installed the paggenger gem using following command

```
rvmsuo gem install passenger
```

After that when I am tried to install passenger module for apache2 using following command

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Installation start, all dependencies are checked and passed, and at time of compilation, i got following error,

```
g++ ApplicationPoolServerExecutable.cpp System.o Utils.o Logging.o -o 
    ApplicationPoolServerExecutable -I.. -D_REENTRANT -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -Wall -
    I/usr/local/include   -DPASSENGER_DEBUG ../boost/src/libboost_thread.a -lpthread
    g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See <URL:http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
    For Debian GNU/Linux specific bug reporting instructions, see <an url goes here>

    rake aborted!
    Command failed with status (1): [g++ ApplicationPoolServerExecutable.cpp Sy...]
    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-
    2.0.6/Rakefile:161
```

I have check the apache error log but, i did't got any clue.

Comment: One gentleman has provide a negative vote for this question, before vote down if the person specify clearly why he did so, it will help full to take corrective measurement. If any one have any problem to understand the problem, or whatever, before voting down you can ask by adding comment... any way thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to run it in a virtual machine which consist of 256 mb ram. When i have allocate more memory (1 gb) to that virtual machine, the problem solved .

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have enough memory, you may be able to make some temporary adjustments on your Linux machine.

```
# Add 2GB of swap space
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1k count=2048k
mkswap /swap
swapon /swap

# Set overcommit to 100
sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio=100

# Set swappiness (encourages more swapping)
sysctl vm.swappiness=50
```

After this, retry.  If all is well, a simple reboot should undo these changes or, of course, you can set the sysctl's back to their original values and remove the swap.  Keep in mind a reboot won't free the disk space, you'll need to `rm /swap` after reboot.